# Sum up all values from a child node and pass the sum value to another child node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem passing the values of child "like" to child "post" (node "postLikes"). Here's my Json tree : 
[image]

Here's my listener for the button like event :

```
mDatabaseRefLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserLike userLike = new UserLike();
        if(mProcessLike){

            if(dataSnapshot.child(mPostKey).hasChild(mUserId)){
                mDatabaseRefLike.child(mPostKey).child(mUserId).removeValue();
                mProcessLike = false;

            }else {
                mDatabaseRefLike.child(mPostKey).child(mUserId).setValue(1);
                userLike.setUserLikes(1);
                mProcessLike = false;

                for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    UserLike getLikes= snap.getValue(UserLike.class);
                    int gLikes = getLikes.getUserLikes();

                    gLikes += gLikes;

                    mDatabaseRefPost.child(mPostKey).child("postLikes").setValue(gLikes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I already spent days to solve this problem, and it seems I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Which data did `mDatabaseRefLike` and `mDatabaseRefPost` pointing into?

Comment: @koceeng `mDatabaseRefLike` is pointing to child "like" while `mDatabaseRefPost` is to child "post".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this: (I've included comment so that it can be understood easier)

```
mDatabaseRefLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // sorry I remove userLike object because I don't quite understand what is that for
        
        // get count data first before it's changed
        int likeCounter = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

        // here we add/remove value in "like/postId/userId"
        // and update likeCounter value
        if(dataSnapshot.child(mPostKey).hasChild(mUserId)) {
            mDatabaseRefLike.child(mPostKey).child(mUserId).removeValue();
            likeCounter--;
            
        } else {
            mDatabaseRefLike.child(mPostKey).child(mUserId).setValue(true);
            likeCounter++;
        }

        // then we update value in "post/postId/postLikes"
        mDatabaseRefPost.child(mPostKey).child("postLikes").setValue(likeCounter);
    }
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

> Note:
>
> Sorry it takes me long to understand your code. First I think your code just make simple thing more complicated. But when I tried to solve the problem, it actually is a good practice. Great job :)

Comment: Thank you sir! Your answer solves the problem, Although i got another bug where if a user liked another post the value will be the count of the node of child "like". But that would be in another thread(Question) I guess. Again, Thank you for taking time to solve the problem! :)

Comment: I missed analyzing this part. Knowing snapshot variable contains the target of the `ValueEventListener`, so I have come up with the solution of targeting the node "mPostKey". 
**Problem** - `int likeCounter = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();`
**Solution** - `int likeCounter = (int)dataSnapshot.child(mPostKey).getChildrenCount();`

I have just commented it here, just in case someone has the same problem. Happy Coding! :)